# Is Anti-Dark Matter a thing?

Tags: dark-matter, antimatter

Could there be such thing as anti-dark matter? If there is anti regular matter, why not anti-dark matter? If there is no such thing as anti-dark matter, why?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it is a thing.

Weakly Interacting Massive Particles (aka [WIMPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_interacting_massive_particles)) are thought to come in matter and anti-matter forms and have a self-annihilation cross-section in order to produce the "correct" amount of dark matter (in relation to photons) that we measure today.

As the opening paragraph of the wikipedia article on WIMPS states - there are a number of experiments searching for the photons associated with Annihilation of WIMP anti-WIMP pairs, from which it appears that there is expected to be a [neutrino and a gamma ray signature](https://astrobites.org/2013/03/02/the-search-for-wimp-annihilation-in-the-sun/) or even the presence of anti-matter (positrons) that might be detected in cosmic ray experiments.

Of the other dark matter candidates - whether [sterile neutrinos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sterile_neutrino) have an anti-particle depends on whether they are [Majorana fermions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorana_fermion) or not. The hypothetical [axion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axion) I think is its own anti-particle (a chargeless boson) and there are no annihilation-type experiments for their detection that I can find.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the composition of the dark matter.

From the description I read it is clear that MACHOs (composed of normal baryonic matters) can have anti-objects, and there are also [anti-WIMPs](http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/objects/heapow/archive/normal_galaxies/fermi_m31.html).

I am not sure about the Axion, it seem to be a different beast (on par with the photon that is its own anti-particle).

Comment: a photon is considered to be its own antiparticle.